# jQuery UI Tabs - showing content from other <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So jQuery UI Tabs is currently working, I'm also with blueimp Gallery to display a slideshow.

That gallery needs to display images using the `<a>` tag, jQuery UI Tabs takes it Menus from `<a>` tags.

So I'm seeing in my Tabs - all types of symbols etc, as opposed to just my content.

My a tag is clashing, as when I remove the images.. the content displays properly

[image]

**This displays Photos**

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="images/br/GK Birthright.jpg"></a>
  <a href="images/br/GK Birthright 2.jpg"</a>
  <a href="images/br/GK Birthright 3.jpg"</a>
  <a href="images/br/GK-BR1.jpg"</a>
</div>
```

**JS for Slideshow** - if gets all the 'a'

```
<script>
blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
        carousel: true,
        startSlideshow: false
    }
);
</script>
```

**This displays Tabs**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">United States of America</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">United Kingdom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Canada</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: take a close look at your <a> tags only the first one is correct the rest are broken, they are missing the closing bracket '>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are needing img tags not ... or maybe both... try..

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="images/br/GK Birthright.jpg"><img src="images/br/GK Birthright.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/br/GK Birthright 2.jpg"><img src="images/br/GK Birthright 2.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/br/GK Birthright 3.jpg"><img src="images/br/GK Birthright 3.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/br/GK-BR1.jpg"><img src="images/br/GK-BR1.jpg" /></a>
```

what are are seeing is the image meta data...this is because you mistakenly left the closing bracket off your  tags...

```
 <a href="images/br/GK Birthright 3.jpg"(need closing > here)</a>
```

the very first  is correct..in your current code